# Graphene Django: Change field names

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

If I have a Django model with fields names in french like this (*nom* is the french translation of *name*):

```
class Categorie(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
```

Is it possible to configure a GraphQL Query with Graphene Django in order to query the graph with an english translation of the field (using *name* instead of *nom*):

```
query {
  allCategories {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

When you define your `DjangoObjectType` try this:

```
class CategorieType(DjangoObjectType):
    name = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        model = Categorie
        exclude_fields = ('nom',)  # Do this only if you want to HIDE "nom"

    def resolve_name(self, info):
        return self.nom
```

Comment: Please note that you will need a second `info` parameter to the resolver for this to work. I.e. `def resolve_name(self, info):`.

Comment: How do we return `ID` instead of `id`?

Comment: Follow the same pattern for the "name" field as shown, except the field type for ID should be type of your `id` field, presumably `graphene.Int()`